# Put other things in eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse

I have a `projects` folder in my home directory that I use as my eclipse workspace. I have some other projects (like writing) that I don't use eclipse for in other directories, but I would like to move them into the `projects` folder (since they are projects, after all). Given that the `projects` folder is also an eclipse workspace, are there any downsides to moving non-eclipse projects into it, as long as I don't touch the `.metadata` folder? I have googled and searched SO for a discussion on this, but have not found any useful advice one way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15919_01/wlp.1032/e14246/prep.htm) from Oracle about setting up the Oracle Enterprise Pack for eclipse that advises keeping *all* of your projects, including eclipse projects, outside of the eclipse workspace, so they can be more easily managed by source control. I am going with this approach.